# how to send html email using php

Tags: php, email, html-email

I would like to use <<< to send html email in php. So far i remember it works great previously but not working right now.

```
//ALL HTML MUST BE LEFT ALLIGNED.
$php_var="variable value";
$body = <<<EmailBody
<html>
<body>
$php_var
</body>
</html>
EmailBody; //EmailBody will not show in Email.
$headers = 'From: info@mydomain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: info@mydomain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$subject="Test HTML Email";
$body="test email from mydomain";
$to="aminulsumon@gmail.com";
mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers); //$header type should be html
```

any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: There should NOT be anything before AND after `EmailBody;` - **IF** - `EmailBody; //EmailBody will not show in Email.` is part of your actual code, remove `//EmailBody will not show in Email.` including the space between the end of `EmailBody;` and `//` - Read the documentation on heredoc http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: You have to use 'content-type: text/html' to send html in email

Comment: if nothing before and after EmailBody then where should i write code to send email? Would you please paste complete code as an example which works fine.

Comment: Meaning this `EmailBody;` (the closing identifier), is all there should be on that line, nothing else after; you have `//EmailBody will not show in Email.`. Using [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), would throw you an error such as `Unexpected end of file` or similar error.

Comment: I guess my explanations mean squat. I teach, I just don't "drop" code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the comment on the end of:

```
EmailBody; //EmailBody will not show in Email.
```

So it is only:

```
EmailBody;
```

Also you define `$body` twice, so take out:

```
$body="test email from mydomain";
```

Answer (score 1):

There should NOT be anything before AND/or after `EmailBody;`; it being the closing identifier.

- [**Read the documentation on heredoc**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Use this:

```
//ALL HTML MUST BE LEFT ALLIGNED.
$php_var="variable value";
$body = <<<EmailBody
<html>
<body>
$php_var
</body>
</html>
EmailBody;
$headers = 'From: info@mydomain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: info@mydomain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$subject="Test HTML Email";
$body="test email from mydomain";
$to="aminulsumon@gmail.com";
mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers); //$header type should be html
```

---

Having something (space, text, etc.) after the closing identifier, will result in the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in....(path to file) on line X

had error reporting been set

- **http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php**

Add this just before your opening `<?php` tag:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one basic example to send html in email -

```
$to = 'abcd@gmail.com';
$from = "sender@gmail.com"; // sender

$subject = "Test email";

$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= "<p>This is The Email Address</p><br><span class='nonLink'>responder@example.com</span>";
$message .= '<br/><a href="http://www.yourwebsite.com/verify.php?email='.$from.'&hash='.$hash.'">click here to complete your registration</a>';
$message .= '</body></html>';

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset: utf8\r\n";
// Additional headers
$headers .= "From: <$from>" . "\r\n";

// Mail it
if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    echo "email sent successfully";
}
```

Comment: The OP states - *"I would like to use `<<<` to send html email in php"* - That's [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax; you're missing the whole point.